# jQuery UI using :tabbable to find next and previous tabbable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jQuery UI [`:tabbable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabbable-selector/) selector to select the next and previous input elements on a page. I have the following html

```
<div id="section1">1.
    <input type="text" />2.
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div id="section2">3.
    <input type="text" />4.
    <input type="text" />5.
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

and the following javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").on("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 40) $(this).next(":tabbable").focus();
        else if (event.keyCode == 38) $(this).prev(":tabbable").focus();
    });
});
```

The selector seems to work fine within a div. For instance if I am in input 3 and press down it will go to input 4. However if I press up the selector cannot find input 2. I can't seem to figure out how to find the previous tabbable element on the page.

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9w5J/)

Comment: `.next` and `.previous` don't work this way. They're only looking at the *immediate following or preceding sibling matching the selector*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.index()` of the input elements as a way to shift between them.

```
$("input").on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        $('input').eq(parseInt($('input').index($(this)), 10) + 1).focus();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        $('input').eq(parseInt($('input').index($(this)), 10) - 1).focus();
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v9w5J/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").on("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            $nextTabbable = $(this).next(":tabbable").length
                ? $(this).next(":tabbable")
                : $(this).parent().next().find(":tabbable").first()
            ;
            $nextTabbable.focus();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            $prevTabbable = $(this).prev(":tabbable").length
                ? $(this).prev(":tabbable")
                : $(this).parent().prev().find(":tabbable").last()
            ;
            $prevTabbable.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/fR43G/)